# Locate React MUI Element with Selenium script

Tags: javascript, reactjs, selenium, testing

I am building web page for a real state company. This web is built with a react frontend and a nodejs backend. And I am tryng to test it using a selenium script with a broswerStack server. But I am unable to lcate the element I want to interact with I have tried many different things but nothing seems to work. This is the button I am trying to click.

The button class is a MUI Button.

```
function NotMobileTopbar() {

    return (
        <Grid container columnSpacing={{xs: 1, sm: 2, md: 1}} justifyContent="flex-end" >

            <Grid >
                <Button sx={{ fontWeight: "bold"}} id="PropiedadesButton" variant="text" color="inherit" size="large" LinkComponent={Link} to="/propiedades" >Propiedades</Button>
            </Grid>

            <Grid>
                <Button sx={{ fontWeight: "bold"}} className="IniciarSesionButton" LinkComponent={Link} to="/login">Iniciar sesión</Button>
            </Grid>

        </Grid>
    )
}
```

And I put the className as IniciarSessionButton.

Then in my webpage it appears like this.

[image]

And my selenium code is the following:

```
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
const assert = require("assert");
const fs = require('fs');

async function runTestWithCaps (capabilities) {
  let driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .usingServer('')
    .withCapabilities({
      ...capabilities,
      ...capabilities['browser'] && { browserName: capabilities['browser']}  // Because NodeJS language binding requires browserName to be defined
    }).build()

  await driver.navigate().to("https://phindi-front.onrender.com/")

  driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css("MuiGrid-root css-vj1n65-MuiGrid-root")).click()
  .then(() => console.log("AA"))
  .catch((err) => console.log(err))
  await driver.quit()
}

const capabilities1 = {
    'bstack:options' : {
        "os": "Windows",
        "osVersion": "11",
        "buildName" : "browserstack-build-1",
        "sessionName" : "Parallel test 1",
    },
    "browserName": "chrome",
    "browserVersion": "103.0",
    }
 const capabilities2 = {
    'bstack:options' : {
        "os": "Windows",
        "osVersion": "11",
        "buildName" : "browserstack-build-1",
        "sessionName" : "Parallel test 2",
    },
    "browserName": "firefox",
    "browserVersion": "103.0",
    }
runTestWithCaps(capabilities1);
runTestWithCaps(capabilities2);
```

Does anyone know hot to click that button?

I tried many different things like selecting the text that appears on the web or using xpath but I do not understand it

Comment: try with XPATH of //a[@href='/login']  (I think the syntax is wrong in your css selector, and you're also dealing with multiple CSS styles there... when the class attribute has spaces, you know there multiple style classes associated with it... style classes are a lousy way to select as they are not always unique.)

Comment: that class might have been removed because you don't have a style definition for it. You should use the href: `a[href="/login"]`